# How to disable page reloading for sending form via ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, forms, jquery

I have simple form and I want send data from form via ajax request.
I try this:

```
    $('form#station').submit(
            function() {
                console.log('form submit without reloading');
                var coords = station.geometry.getCoordinates();
                 console.log(data);
                $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: '/admin/station/add-ajax',
                            method: 'post',
                            data: {},
                            success: function(result) {
                                console.log('succcess');
                            }
                        }
                );
                return false;
            }
    );
```

Why is page reloaded?

Comment: To be your code looks correct to me. Are you sure there aren't any JS errors within your code? Could you post what the object `station` is?

Comment: No, I haven't any errors. When I added preventDefaults() all get works fine.

Comment: If you use event.preventDefault(); you should pass the event object through the function because IE will have issues if you don't. So:

    $('form#station').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

Comment: As a test, comment out `var coords = station.geometry.getCoordinates();` - does not seem to be used (at this point) and any syntax error there would not allow the `return false;` statement to actually prevent the submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use event.preventDefault(); you should pass the event object through the function because IE will have issues if you don't. So:

```
$('form#station').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // e = event
});
```

I would generally use return false; and you can put it before all the other code, to be sure it stops submission before the ajax runs. It could just be waiting too long fetching data before it actually stops the submit. Hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try including event.preventDefault(); 
Should work.